# for loop syntax

Tags: javascript, html, css

Someone can explain me this part of code please.

```js
function parent (elem, selector ) {
   for ( ; elem && elem !== document; elem = elem.parentNode ) {
        if ( elem.matches( selector ) ) return elem;
    }
}
```

I understand what he does, but I don't understand the start of loop exactly this part : `for ( ; elem && elem !== document; ...`

Usually we have to specify a starting number for the iteration, it's very strange for me this loop.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the first part of the loop configuration is for setting up an index, the second part is where the looping condition goes. If the condition is not based on the index, then the index can be omitted. In this case, the loop cares about the passed argument `elem`, not an index.

In fact, all 3 configuration sections of a `for` are optional (making the `for` more like a `while`).  From **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)**:

> **Syntax**
>
> `for ([initialization]; [condition]; [final-expression])`
>
> `statement`

*(As you may be aware, the use of `[]` in an argument list being show for syntax purposes means optional.)*

Here's an example:

```js
var obj = {}; // Not null

// Keep looping as long as obj is not null (which it isn't to start)
for ( ; obj != null; obj=null) {
  console.log("Loop!");   // First time through the loop, obj != null so loop will go
}  // After first iteration, obj will become null (because of 3rd part of loop config)
   // so loop will terminate
```

Having said that, this is certainly not an elegant way to use JS `for` syntax. The logic could be handled in a more readable way with a `while` loop:

```
function parent (elem, selector ) {
  while (elem && elem !== document){
    if (elem.matches( selector )) {
      return elem;
    }
    elem = elem.parentNode;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may refer to [this](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp). The structure of a for-loop consists of three statements, all of which are optional. The first statement executes before the loop starts, so typically, it is used for variable declaration. The second statement is used to define conditions. The third statement Is called upon each loop, hence it is typically used to increment or decrement values, or assign new values. 
When all of these statements are not there as below, it means that it is an infinite loop.

```
for (;;)
```

When the first statement is not there, which is the case in your example, then there was need to declare variables or have a code block to execute before the for loop starts. However, there is still condition that must be satisfied in order to keep the loops going (statement 2), and block that is called upon each loop (statement 3).

**Statement 1:** None    // If there was any, it would have been called at the beginning

**Statement 2:** elem && elem !== document    // Decides whether to continue looping

**Statement 3:** elem = elem.parentNode    // Called each loop

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing that specifies a `for` loop *must* use an iterator. The `for` loop syntax was invented because it is very common to iterate over a range of numbers, and doing that with a `while` loop always looks something like this:

```
var counter = 0;
while (counter < 10) {
    // do something...
    counter++;
}
```

Because it was so common to see a variable used as an iterator, then an expression to be checked in a `while` loop, and an increment operation at the end of the `while` loop body, some clever programmers created the `for` loop syntax so that these parts could all be stated upfront in a concise manner: `for ([initialization]; [condition]; [final-expression])`. Note well that any of these parts can actually be omitted - only the semi-colons are actually required inside the parenthesis.

The author of this code doesn't need an iterator, however, perhaps he or she just likes that all of the necessary pieces are on a single line. You could just as easily write this function with a `while` loop that would look like this:

```
function parent(elem, selector) {
    while (elem && elem !== document) {
        if (elem.matches(selector)) {
            return elem;
        }
        elem = elem.parentNode;
    }
}
```